# How to generate url with language code in drupal7?

Tags: 7

Is there any drupal function to return the url with currently used language.
Like: example.com/en

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL by using following code

```
global $language ;
$lang_name = $language->language ;

$url_current = $GLOBALS['base_url']/$lang_name;
```

Comment: Not quite...you're dividing strings at the moment

Comment: Following links will be helpful for you  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/language/7 https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7

Comment: It means there is not a straight drupal function?

Comment: I've never found a straight function for this. If you find it please share.